# WordPress is giving 500 error

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to update a table in WordPress that I created myself through a plug-in that I created. However I keep getting this error:

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving /add-van-process.php. 
It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Error code: 500
```

This is the PHP that I am using:

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $data = array("model"=>"Ford")
    $wpdb->insert("van_table", $data); 
?>
```

The file name and table name are correct and exist. Anyone got any ideas how to fix this?

much appreciated

edit: I am using WordPress Version Version 3.5.2 if that is needed.

edit: after changing this code to:

```
$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM van_table");
```

I get this error: 
    PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object

Any clues?

Comment: Check out here http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html

500 error usually caused due to htaccess errors.

Comment: @ignat-b How will this affect the plug-in though? When I take that code out and add in basic stuff like echo 'test'; it works.

Comment: 500 errors may be thrown when PHP has an error but error reporting turned off, check your logs Mark :-)

Comment: Ben's suggestion make sence. Please try to use default Wordpress htaccess + check out your server logs.

Comment: This is what is in the logs: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object - I have no idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon on this row:

`$data = array("model"=>"Ford")`

Also, you might want to enable WP_DEBUG - this way you'll see the actual error and not a standard Error 500 message: http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: Ive added that ; - Still no luck and I have enabled the debug. Where would the log files go?

Comment: There is this error in the server logs: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function insert() on a non-object

Comment: It seems like you're trying to access this file directly instead of loading WordPress first, is that the case? See this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9322